# php simplexml_load_file() with password protected url

Tags: php, simplexml, http-authentication

Simple question for the one who knows the answer...

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://url/path/file.xml");
```

This url is `.htaccess` protected, how can I pass the login/password as arguments to the function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://username:password@url/path/file.xml");
```

Try that :)

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` or curl will allow you to set the user authentication using `http://username:password@url/path/file.xml`.

Take the string data and pass into `simplexml_load_string`.

Answer (score 1):

allow_url_fopen and allow_url_include must be turned on in php.ini (or propriertary .htaccess) before you are able to do this. It was most likely not set up on your server and must be changed by hand.

An example .htaccess setup with these values would be:

```
php_value allow_url_fopen 1
php_value allow_url_include 1
```

Comment: Found this same answer here: 
http://forums.phpfreaks.com/index.php?topic=295326.msg1398390#msg1398390.  Unfortunately it doesnt work for me.